# Insert-heavy workloads are CPU-bound or I/O bound

Tags: cassandra, nosql

> Insert-heavy workloads are CPU-bound in Cassandra before becoming
>   memory-bound. (All writes go to the commit log, but Cassandra is so
>   efficient in writing that the CPU is the limiting factor.

Can some body explain me this statement why I/O is not a limiting factor here? I mean as I understand it first heads to I/O and then to CPU.

I took a look at [This StackOverflow question](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDoQFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F16983929%2Fexplanation-required-for-a-statement-in-cassandra-documentation&ei=f9YGVISLMdTkuQT4kIKwBA&usg=AFQjCNG2jkXqIUWBZqikc2z1cNDjSmtJaA&sig2=ivj3OUhtPOnKjw-iqSzZeQ&bvm=bv.74115972,d.c2E) or [Cassndra Incubator](http://cassandra-user-incubator-apache-org.3065146.n2.nabble.com/Are-Writes-disk-bound-rather-than-CPU-bound-td7589191.html)  or [Apache](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cassandra-user/201307.mbox/%3CCE142410.2D5F0%25Dean.Hiller@nrel.gov%3E) email chain but still its not clear for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cassandra keeps a log of items, yes that part is I/O. But this log is appended continueusly. Therefore Cassandra doesn’t need to wait for HDD seek. Looking at HDD Burst write speeds - which are  above 100MB/s this really doesn’t seem like a limiting factor to me. In fact the network would be limiting. But because you probably won’t reach write speeds at which the network becomes limiting, the CPU limitation kicks in.

I hope that now this part of the answer makes sense:

> To process an insert, Cassandra needs to deserialize the messages from the clients, find which nodes should store the data and send messages to those nodes. Those nodes then store the data in an in memory data structure called a Memtable.
>
> This is almost always CPU bound initially. However, as more data is inserted, the memtables grow large and are flushed to disk and new (empty) memtables are created. The flushed memtables are stored in files known as SSTables. There is an ongoing background process called compaction that merges SSTables together into progressively larger and larger files.

by [Richard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2067561/richard) from [Explanation required for a statement in Cassandra documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16983929/explanation-required-for-a-statement-in-cassandra-documentation)

Comment: Awesome !! makes sense; much more clearer now . two questions. 
1.Can you please more insight on correlation between HDD seek and sequential write> and 
2.would like to understand more on the basis of assumption "because you probably won’t reach write speeds at which the network becomes limiting"?
Thanks again

Comment: sequential write can theoretically get up to the write burst speed which is for consumer HDD between 100MB/s and 300MB/s. Server HDD should be even faster than that.  100MB/s translates to roughly 800Mbit/s. Server on which Cassandra is running usually have 1Gbit/s network connection. So to reach even 100MB/s the network bandwidth would already quite limiting. However these are really rough numbers and don't consider a lot of things, just to provide you a picture. In the end consider the amount of data inserting when doing it at a rate of even 50MB/s.